# How do I apply my Vanilla JS Array manipulation method in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image]I am finishing up my REST API and I am trying to convert an array I received from my backend into a Nested Object of Objects or an array of objects, whatever can help me avoid using direct indices to access elements.

I have tried converting the array but I only receive a single object which is one of the many arrays in the multidimensional array. I need it to convert the whole dataset, not to only return one entry.

[image]

Comment: I've solved the basic javascript question of converting a multidimensional array into an array of objects by using Object.assign on each element through map function. The next step is, How do I integrate this vanilla functionality into react?

Answer (score 0):

I took the function designed for a map function of the array object with Object.assign() and placed in the method I am using in my Express backend and sent the data to my react client as an array of already converted Objects.

Mind you this data was received in CSV format.